# Migrating existing Activities application to Fragments

Tags: android

I've an app written for phones. I'm planning on adding Fragments API so that same app runs 1.6 all the way to 3.2. 
However, the problem is with extending FragmentsActivity. My activities are extending a common activity which has all the common functions. Moving them into interface and implementing them is a lot of rework.

What is the best way out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code that was in the base Activity to a base Fragment, then have your Fragments extend that.

Comment: Fragment doesnt have same attributes and methods of Activity. e.g. onCreateOptionsMenu(), etc.

Comment: Well then, I suggest you move that stuff into a base Activity class, and think of this Activity as your Fragment controller class. FragmentActivity has the stuff you need to handle the options menu. What is it you are trying to share exactly?

Comment: My app is very simplistic with List | Detail. right now, both of them extend common abstract activity that handle auth, menu items, dialogs, error handling, sync operations. Would it be wise to have a Base FragmentActivity for Activites that hold Fragments and Base Fragment that's extended by both List and detail Fragments?

Comment: Have your base Activity handle showing/hiding fragments on screen, the menu, popup dialogs, etc. Have each fragment handle it's own business logic. If it's a list, then it's a list. If it shows details, have it show details, don't mix the two. Try to keep the right functionality in the right object.